# DRY way to correct fields with the same validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several tables in Rails that have string fields that must match a set of terms specified by a table, CvTerm (short for controlled_vocabulary). CvTerm serves as a table-and-field specific whitelist; for example, table `Foo` might have a field `Bar` for which the only allowed entries are `Baz`, `Bax`, or `Quux`, for which there would be CvTerms created for each allowed entry.

I wrote a custom validator to ensure that the value a user assigns to these fields matches one of those set for the table; this validator can be used across all models as a one-liner, `validates :field, is_controlled: true`.

```
class IsControlledValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        if options[:has_context]
            allowed_terms = CvTerm.where({
                :related_table => record.class.to_s,
                :related_field => attribute.to_s,
                :context_table => record.related_type
            }).map(&:term)
        else
            allowed_terms = CvTerm.where(:related_table => record.class.to_s, :related_field => attribute.to_s).map(&:term)
        end
        unless allowed_terms.include?(value)
            record.errors[attribute] << "must be included in the allowed terms:\n#{allowed_terms.join("\n")}"
        end
    end
end
```

This is convenient to implement in my models and works nearly as intended, but it's case-sensitive: It would be quite annoying to force the user to manually ensure the case is exactly the same as the initially input allowed term.

Apart from putting such a case-correction in the validator, which I understand is frowned upon, is there a way to do this that doesn't require me to individually case-correct every controlled field?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple things.

1. Use pluck instead of mapping, it is faster on the sql and you don't have to loop over to get the term.
2. instead of doing a straight where do a like or ilike (mysql vs postgres) to remove the case sensitivity
3. (maybe) move your search into a query object.

Comment: These are good performance pointers, although the controlled vocabulary table will usually be small enough that any performance hits will be negligible. I'm more concerned about data consistency - How can I get my users to wind up with a uniform term without having to make sure every last capital letter is properly placed?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do this transform on the backend before saving.  That is the only way you can ensure it is in a specific format.  You could also just do a case insensitive search using the ilike in postgres.